# Need Help Solving Polynomial Equation

Tags: induction

I'm working on an induction problem that basically boils down to this equation:

$$2(-1)^k+ 6(2^k)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1} + (-1)^{k}=0$$

I'm fairly confident that the equation above is the solution to the problem, but I am unable to simplify it further in order to prove the case.

Any help breaking it down would be appreciated.

Comment: if  you simplify $2^k$ and $1/2^{k+1}$ you will be almost there.

Comment: what are you trying to prove in fact?

Comment: This, http://i.imgur.com/6cjzQI6.png
is what I'm trying to prove, using induction (P(k) -> P(k+1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
2(-1)^k + 6(2)^k (- \frac{1}{2})^{k+1} - (-1)^{k+1} =0
$$
Notice $(- \frac{1}{2})^{k+1} = (-1)^{k+1}(2)^{-k-1}$and multiply by $(-1)^{k+1}$
$$
-2 + 6(2)^k(2)^{-k-1}-1=0
$$
Simplify
$$-3 + 6(2)^{-1} =0$$
so finally
$$-3 + 3 =0$$
which is an identity, so your original equation is true for all values of $k$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I had tried to simplify (-1/2)^(k+1) to (-2)^(-k-1), but couldn't take it farther from there.